# Apache not redirect with www problem NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: apache, symfony, redirect, url-rewriting, apache2

I have some issue with my site. When I enter a url address without www I have got error "Your Connection is not Private .. NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID".
So I tried redirect to url with www but redirect not working.
Its application on Symfony 5 framework.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerSignature Off
    DocumentRoot /var/www/release.example/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    DirectoryIndex index.php

<Directory /var/www/example/public>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<FilesMatch \.php$>
# For Apache version 2.4.10 and above, use SetHandler to run PHP as a fastCGI process server
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>





<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin email@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerSignature Off
    DocumentRoot /var/www/release.example/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    DirectoryIndex index.php

<Directory /var/www/release.example/public>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<FilesMatch \.php$>
# For Apache version 2.4.10 and above, use SetHandler to run PHP as a fastCGI process server
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>


Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: whats your desired result? for which hostname u have the certificate ? Is it self signed ? because the the warning/error is default then

Comment: The site working with www so my result is redirect from example.com to https://www.example.com.